# Probability help.

Tags: probability

Did something in class the other day ad it made me curious on what the probability was. There were 19 people in class and each of us had to pick any 5 items out of a list of 12, order did not matter. Then we had to see if anyone else had picked the same items. I was wondering on how exactly to figure out the probability that any 2 people would have the same list?
Also, what if the lists had to be in the same exact order?

Comment: The downvote and the vote to close seem so unreasonable that I suspect someone goes about checking posts by a standard that requires them to prove beyond a reasonable doubt that their question is flawless, and requires the question to be precisely stated.  Both standards are unreasonable.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that there exists at least one pair of people in the class who picked the same items, or the probability that two specific people picked the same items?

Comment: Trying to find out probability of any 2 people in the class having the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to pick $5$ things out of $12$ is $\dbinom{12}5 = 792$.

So the probability that the second person gets a different set of $5$ from the first is $1-\dfrac{1}{792} = \dfrac{791}{792}$.

Given that the first two get different sets, the probability that the third one gets a different set is $1-\dfrac{2}{792} = \dfrac{790}{792}$.

Given that the first three get different sets, the probability that the fourth one gets a different set is $1-\dfrac{3}{792} = \dfrac{789}{792}$.

And so on.

So the probability that all $19$ of them get different sets is
$$
1\times\frac{791}{792}\times\frac{790}{792} \times\frac{789}{792}\times\cdots\times \frac{774}{792}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Michael Hardy, between that and another link I found, I was able to figure it out and get a better understanding.